# Jquery - Autocomplete combobox - live()?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, autocomplete, combobox, live

I have a couple of autocomplete comboboxes in a div.
I have to cut it and put in into another div on some action.
Upon doing so, it does not copy the events of autocomplete.

I am aware of .live() that keeps events binded to elements
all the time.  But how to use .live for this autocomplete
combobox widget. Pls suggest?

thanks in advance.

A code sample as follows:

**HTML Page**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link type="text/css" href="themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.1.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-ui-1.8.13.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.combobox.js"></script> 

<style type="text/css">
   .ui-button { margin-left: -1px; }
   .ui-button-icon-only .ui-button-text { padding: 0.35em; }
   .ui-autocomplete-input { margin: 0; padding: 0.48em 0 0.47em 0.45em; }
   .ui-autocomplete { height: 200px; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden;}
   .ui-menu .ui-menu-item { font-size:8pt; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#combobox").combobox();
        $("#toggle").click(function() {$("#combobox").toggle();});
    })

    function cutpasteCombo(id) {
        $('#pasteHere').html($('#comboCtrl').html());
        $('#comboCtrl').html('');
        $(id).attr('disabled',true);
    }

    </script>     
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id='comboCtrl'>
        <label>Your preferred programming language</label> 
        <select id="combobox" style="width:250px;"> 
            <option value="">Select one...</option> 
            <option value="1">ActionScript</option> 
            <option value="AppleScript">AppleScript</option> 
            <option value="Asp">Asp</option> 
            <option value="BASIC">BASIC</option> 
            <option value="C">C</option> 
            <option value="C++">C++</option> 
            <option value="Clojure">Clojure</option> 
            <option value="COBOL">COBOL</option> 
            <option value="ColdFusion">ColdFusion</option> 
            <option value="Erlang">Erlang</option> 
        </select> 
    </div>
    <br />
    <input type="button" value="Cut & Paste Combo" onclick="cutpasteCombo(this);" />
    <br /><br />

    <div id='pasteHere'>
        Place the combo here...
    </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript: autocomplete-combobox-widget (from jquery)**

```
(function($) {
    $.widget("ui.combobox", {
        _create: function() {
            var self = this,
                    select = this.element.hide(),
                    selected = select.children(":selected"),
                    value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "",
                    theWidth = select.width(); 
            var input = this.input = $("<input style=\"width:" + theWidth + "px\">")
                    //.insertAfter(select)
                    .val(value)
                    .autocomplete({
                        delay: 0,
                        minLength: 0,
                        source: function(request, response) {
                            var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
                            response(select.children("option").map(function() {
                                var text = $(this).text();
                                if (this.value && (!request.term || matcher.test(text)))
                                    return {
                                        label: text.replace(
                                            new RegExp(
                                                "(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" +
                                                $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term) +
                                                ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"
                                            ), "<strong>$1</strong>"),
                                        value: text,
                                        option: this
                                    };
                            }));
                        },
                        select: function(event, ui) {
                            ui.item.option.selected = true;
                            self._trigger("selected", event, {
                                item: ui.item.option
                            });
                        },
                        change: function(event, ui) {
                            if (!ui.item) {
                                var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex($(this).val()) + "$", "i"),
                                    valid = false;
                                select.children("option").each(function() {
                                    if ($(this).text().match(matcher)) {
                                        this.selected = valid = true;
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                });
                                if (!valid) {
                                    // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
                                    $(this).val("");
                                    select.val("");
                                    input.data("autocomplete").term = "";
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left");
                    var span = $("<span style=\" white-space: nowrap;\"></span>").append(input).insertAfter(select);

            input.data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
                return $("<li></li>")
                        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                        .append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>")
                        .appendTo(ul);
            };

            this.button = $("<button type='button'>&nbsp;</button>")
                    .attr("tabIndex", -1)
                    .attr("title", "Show All Items")
                    .insertAfter(input)
                    .button({
                        icons: {
                            primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                        },
                        text: false
                    })
                    .removeClass("ui-corner-all")
                    .addClass("ui-corner-right ui-button-icon")
                    .click(function() {
                        // close if already visible
                        if (input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible")) {
                            input.autocomplete("close");
                            return;
                        }

                        // work around a bug (likely same cause as #5265)
                        $(this).blur();

                        // pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
                        input.autocomplete("search", "");
                        input.focus();
                    });
        },

        destroy: function() {
            this.input.remove();
            this.button.remove();
            this.element.show();
            $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call(this);
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are copying and pasting the HTML. You need to use `detach()` on the actual combobox item and then `append()` to add it to the new location.

EDIT: try `$("#pastehere").append($("#combobox").detach());`.